# Fetch Local Data from CoreData using RestKit 0.2

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit-0.20

I am facing some issues in fetching data from CoreData in the RestKit world. I am able to successfully map JSON data from server to my NSManagedObject Entities. But I don't have any idea how to fetch data that RestKit stored in my local storage.

I tried using the code below to fetch data from local storage:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
//  NSManagedObjectContext* context =  [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                            entityForName:@"DTUser" inManagedObjectContext: context];
  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:entityDescription];
  NSArray *dtContents = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
  NSLog(@"Content :%@", dtContents);
```

But it returns an empty array.

Comment: What should be loaded and when are you running that code? Have you set the defaultStore?

Comment: @Wain : Yes I have set the default store. I am able to correctly map JSON data to my Core Data Entities. And after mapping when i do 

 int count =  [context countForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" predicate:nil error:nil];

it gives me correct count of entities. But once i close(terminate) the app and  again open the app and again execute the code below:

int count =  [context countForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" predicate:nil error:nil];

It returns count as zero.

Comment: And you've debugged to check you have a valid context and you've checked the fetch request error? And how are you creating the Core Data stack?

Comment: Yes it is returning valid context. I even tried doing 

   BOOL success = [context saveToPersistentStore:nil];
and then also data is not saving in the database.

Comment: So probably we need to look at how the model / store / context are created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `addInMemoryPersistentStore:` does not save to disk so when the app closes all data is gone. Look at using `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:` instead.

Comment: Thanx a lot agin for your reply.